# Combine two mysql group queries

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a web app to create tournaments and as i have learned PHP in the course of this project, so my skills aren't probably the best.

I have an identifier in my database `day2_semifinal` or `day2_additional` which basically identifies the type of semifinal.

So my first query is:

```
$numberquery = mysql_query("
SELECT *
FROM tourneyplayers
INNER JOIN results
    on (resultid=r_id)
INNER JOIN players
    ON (p_id=playerid)
INNER JOIN tourneys
    on (T_Id=tourneyid)
WHERE tourneyid='$tourneyid' and
      in_day2 = 1 and
      day2_semifinal IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY day2_semifinal
ORDER BY agegroupid",$connection);
```

This will get me all the semifinal groups, i'll iterate over them and query all the players in group:

```
$semigroup = $group['day2_semifinal'];
$playerQuery = mysql_query("
SELECT *
FROM tourneyplayers
INNER JOIN results
    on (r_id=resultid)
INNER JOIN players
    on (p_id=playerid)
WHERE tourneyid='$tourneyid' AND
      day2_semifinal = '$semigroup' and
      in_day2 = 1
 ORDER BY day2startplace",$connection);
```

Now after i've created tables and echoed all the data from player queries for `day2_semifinal`, i run another query:

```
$numberquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tourneyplayers INNER JOIN results on (resultid=r_id) INNER JOIN players ON (p_id=playerid) WHERE tourneyid='$tourneyid' and in_day2 = 1 and day2_additional_nosemi IS NOT NULL AND day2_additional_nosemi <> 0 GROUP BY day2_additional_nosemi ORDER BY agegroupid",$connection);
```

Which is fairly similar to the first one, only thing different is `day2_semifinal` identifiers have changed to `day2_additional`. After that query, i'll again, iterate over the `day2_additional_nosemi` groups and query the players inside of them:

```
$additionalgroup = $group['day2_additional_nosemi'];
$playerQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tourneyplayers INNER JOIN results on (r_id=resultid) INNER JOIN players on (p_id=playerid) WHERE tourneyid='$tourneyid' AND day2_additional_nosemi = '$additionalgroup' and in_day2 = 1 ORDER BY day2startplace",$connection);
```

Now this works, but this creates an issue with ordering, since the first query orders them by `agegroupid` but only for players in `day2_semifinal` (and i'd like to have `day2_additional` players ordered together with `day2_semifinal`). If i run another query the previous data has already been echoed and ordering is not right. How could i concatenate two `$numberquery` queries in order to select players after them as well?

Comment: remove mysql_*. it is now remove from php7 for security reason, use mysqli_ or pdo

Comment: I'll move onto that in my next project, i'm currently still learning and the area i'm modifying is not public.

Comment: Your first query is invalid because you are selecting all columns while using `GROUP BY`.  What are you actually trying to aggregate in the first query?

Comment: https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Now it seems to me i've been using group by just to get the count for all the different groups and their representative names in order to iterate over them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering my own question as i figured out a way to do this. What i did, was removed `ORDER BY`from both queries and created a new query which concatenated the two with `UNION`:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT *
FROM tourneyplayers as tp1
INNER JOIN results as r1
    on (tp1.resultid=r1.r_id)
INNER JOIN players as p1
    ON (p1.p_id=tp1.playerid)
WHERE tp1.tourneyid=96 and
      tp1.in_day2 = 1 and
      r1.day2_semifinal IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY r1.day2_semifinal
UNION ALL
SELECT * 
FROM tourneyplayers as tp2
INNER JOIN results as r2
 on (tp2.resultid=r2.r_id) 
INNER JOIN players as p2
 ON (p2.p_id=tp2.playerid) 
WHERE tp2.tourneyid=96 and 
 tp2.in_day2 = 1 and 
 r2.day2_additional_nosemi IS NOT NULL AND 
 r2.day2_additional_nosemi <> 0 
 GROUP BY r2.day2_additional_nosemi
) t ORDER BY t.agegroupid;
```